# Submitting a form which multi different fields on different tabs using jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal. The modal will show information about one product. Inside the modal, I have 3 tabs details, image and specification.  Product will have an image, details and specification.

When user click edit, the modal appears and show details tab by default.

All the information is displayed using HTML form because i would like information to be editable. So user can edit details, image and specification.

I have save button at the bottom of modal, clicking save button should submit the details, image and specification information using the ajax.

**My question:**
I done simple data submission using ajax before. But this is complicated for me. How can i can send all the data from all 3 tabs using JQuery. When user press save button what script I should right?

When user press save button, I want all date to be saved.

Can someone help me with start please.

Many Thanks.

**Here is images of modal.**

[Modal tab 1 - details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqvxH.png)

[modal tab 2 - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMkKk.png)

[modal tab 3 - specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1iOp.png)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue and problem here to work around is how to "handle" with the image situation. As saving image data in session and passing it from "tab" to "tab" is difficult I would do some trick here:

1) Each time user uses "choose file" button you should send the data to server and save it as temporary image file. For example, in database or file folder where you save images, create another folder for temporary images and each time use "changes" (use onchange JavaScript listener) image data in modal, send it to the server.

2) As for other type of data, you need to use `localStorage` functionality of JavaScript.

In modalBody you have three different tabs, when you click on each of them, you update its content. So you need to have function like this.

```
function onTabChange()
{
    var formElements = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");
    for(var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++)
    {
        if(formElements[i].value !== "") //if input value is empty it means user hasn't modified or added anything and we don't need to save "empty" data
        {
            localStorage.setItem(formElements[i].name, formElements[i].value);
        }
    }
}
```

So with this function we have ability to pass data values from "tab" to "tab" and have them saved in browser's local storage. As for image we have it in temporary folder which is updated each time user changes image data in form.

After user clicks on "Submit" button

```
function onSubmit()
{
    var formData = new FormData(); //create formData object, 
        formData.append("Description", localStorage.getItem("Description"); 
        //using JQuery or pure JavaScript you add data to formData object from localStorage. 
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            xmlHttp.onreadyStatechange = function()
            {
                if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200)
                {
                    var responseText = xmlHttp.responseText; 
                    alert(responseText);
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("POST", "../Server.php");
            xmlHttp.send(formData);
}
```